# click second radio button with java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i want to klick on the second radio button with java/selenium.
Ids are dynamic and i dont know why xpath dont work.
It would be really helpful if you guys can show me how this works.

HTML

```
   <div class="form-radiobutton-group group-horizontal" id="id29">
            <div class="form-radiobutton-element">
                <span class="form-radiobutton-wrapper">
                    <input class="salutation_f feedback-panel-trigger wicket-id29" id="id4" name="personaldataPanel:salutation:choices" value="radio9" type="radio">
                    <label for="id4" class=""></label>
                </span>
                <label for="id4">
                    Frau
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-radiobutton-element">
                <span class="form-radiobutton-wrapper">
                    <input class="salutation_m feedback-panel-trigger wicket-id29" id="id3" name="personaldataPanel:salutation:choices" value="radio11" type="radio">
                    <label for="id3" class=""></label>
                </span>
                <label for="id3">
                    Herr
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Code right now

```
WebElement m = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/span/input"));
m.click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate `radio button` using `By.xpath` with their label text as below :-

- To click radio button with the label text `Frau` :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[../following-sibling::label[contains(.,'Frau')]]")).click();
  ```
- To click radio button with the label text `Herr` :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[../following-sibling::label[contains(.,'Herr')]]")).click();
  ```

**Edited** :- If you are getting exception that click would receive by other element, need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible on `DOM` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[../following-sibling::label[contains(.,'Herr')]]")));
el.click();
```

If you are still facing same issue then try to click using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i get this error Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (358.5, 262). Other element would receive the click: <label for="id4" class=""></label>

Comment: @Toffa I think you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present on the dom..:)

Comment: god thank you, update works ! I would never have finished without your help.

Comment: @Toffa you welcome... Glad to help you. please accept the answer as well if it helped...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work...:)

Answer (score 2):

To click the radio button with the label "Frau":

```java
WebElement m = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "//input[@id=//label[normalize-space(.)='Frau']/@for]"));

m.click();
```

Or:

```java
WebElement m = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "id(//label[normalize-space(.)='Frau']/@for)"));

m.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='the label text']").click();
```

by this way, you can find out the name of the label and click on the particular radio button by this.

Answer (score 0):

```
element=//input[@id=//label[normalize-space(.)='Frau']/@for]

public void javascriptclick(String element)
    { 
        WebElement webElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",webElement);   
        System.out.println("javascriptclick"+" "+ element);
        }
```